# Why I Cannot Edit any created file in my local VSCode ( I create these files and no file is open elsewhere)?

Tags: file, edit

Even after reinstall vscode on my laptop , I got the same problem ; when I create a dockerfile or a requieremnts.txt file or any other code files , after creating them I cannot edit the content of the files, nor adding new contents ?

Do you know why ? , and how to solve this?

Greetings

[I cannot edit simple requirments.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXwWt.png)